# GIF Support for Iphone

Tags: iphone, nsdata, gif

My Sires, My Dames (ah.. just another knightly thing,...)

I have a question, I have been battling with this for days, here's my scenario:

I have an HTTP response which contains a link to a GIF Image, the GIF image then is converted into an NSData, and later on used to populate an ImageView. Expectedly or Unexpectedly, only the first frame/transition of the GIF is shown. Simply said, the image loads but doesn't animate.

What I want to know if there is native support for GIF in iPhone, likewise I found an extended class here [SCGifExample](https://github.com/shichangone/SCGifExample)
which seems to appear to work only when I import the GIF image within the app, but not when the image is coming from a URI->NSData.

I don't want to create multiple images then create an array of images because that is not gonna work my setup as it will give a lot of load to the server and the client.

I've made my search here at SO, but I didn't found any substantial result to stop me from posting my own question as a matter of fact I found many questions here related to iphone+gif are left unanswered.

I do have a suspicion, and I was hoping somebody could help me figure out and understand it. I suspect that the GIF Animation/Transition is "LOST" during the conversion from Image to NSDATA format. But I don't have any concrete evidence to back this up tho.

Here's how I convert the image into NSData;

```
contentURI = http://gta.champion.com/content?cmsFileId=513af9e9-a96d-4a56-8239-92be273393e0&mt=image/gif //lets just assume that when view using the browser, this would display the image.

NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: contentURI]];
```

If there was somebody else who came victor of this plight, please help me to conquer such feat also.

Comment: Just gonna throw this out there, `UIWebView` supports GIF animations...

Comment: Wow, wish I could answer your question... you should be knighted! ;)

Comment: @esqew No, no, no. Why would you instantiate such a heavy object just to display an animated picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is an alternate , but it depends on the case you have.But let me share the idea with you because using the `UIWebView` solved my problem since I just need to Animate a single image i.e Advertisement.

**Here is the code Snippet :**

```
UIWebView *webV = [[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:appDel.isiPad==TRUE?CGRectMake(260, 35, 500, 100):CGRectMake(40, 18, 250, 60)] autorelease] ;
                webV.delegate =self;
                webV.multipleTouchEnabled=NO;
                [webV setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                webV.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
                [webV loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YourImageUrl"]]];
```

**And implement their delegate methods :**

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Comment: I still want to resist using the UIWebView due to what I believe that the UIWebView is an overkill, and its heavy as Wayne Hartman commented on the original question, its heavy, (but if this would should my problem, and that it will not pose future mem issues) then so be it.

Comment: one question tho... on the event the uri failed to be retrieved how do you handle it? Likewise, if no handler is existing will I get a 404? hmmm. let me try this tho.

Comment: @paulpolo For this you need to check your NSData if not nil then used this data to load your webView. Additionally as a precaution, you can also use the didFailLoadWithError too for handling the request.

Comment: For the meantime this answer is the closest solution to solve my issue, hopefully, until big giant APPLE supports GIF natively. However, this doesn't mean that this is the specific solution to my problem / the issue. There are still things you need to consider, like whats the difference between a UIWebView vs. UIImageView in terms of load times, memory mgmt. etc... Programming is a task of deciding how and when to use a specific tool, and most of the time its about thinking out of the box (just my 2cents tho).

Comment: @paulpolo Yes you are right bro ... but sometime we have to find some easy alternate rather than spending lot of time on a single point. As client always on top of us ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately iOS does not support GIF images, also you cannot use them for animations. If you use GIF images, the imageview will show the first frame of that image, nothing more.

Please refer [**UIImage**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the supported formats.

[image: Image Formats]

Comment: It is true that UIImage does not support animated GIF files directly, but they can be read with the ImageIO Framework in any recent version of iOS. See Wayne's link below, but note that the animated GIF reading libs I have seen online all suffer from a fatal flaw that will crash your app if the GIF is too long to fit into memory.

Comment: @MoDJ: I appreciate your comment. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

While Apple's APIs do not support animated GIFs out-of-the-box, there is a user-created solution that is just as effective:

LBGIFImage:
https://github.com/larcus94/LBGIFImage

Answer (score 0):

See what I found out about showing animated gif in iOS. http://iosnotestoremember.blogspot.com/2013/01/showing-animated-gif-in-ios.html

I hope this helps.